# VBA: Range defaults to 65536 rows (excel 2003) how do I increase it for more rows?

Tags: vba, excel, range, pivot-table

The below code works fine for data having 65536 rows or less but gives a "Type Mismatch" error for more rows than that. I believe it has something to do with the code originally being intended for use on Excel 2003.

Can you please help me figure this one out so that it takes more than 65536 rows?

```
Sub CreatePivot()

ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Range("A1").Select

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim FinalCol As Long
Set WSD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PivotTable")

' Define input area and set up a Pivot Cache
FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
FinalCol = WSD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = WSD.Cells(1, 1).Resize(FinalRow, FinalCol)
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=PRange)


'create pivot table from the above cache
Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WSD.Cells(2, FinalCol + 2), _
TableName:=”dskpivot”)

'turn off updating while building the table
PT.ManualUpdate = True

'add fields rows and columns


PT.AddFields _
RowFields:="Location"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Traffic"), "Sum of Traffic"
End With

PT.ManualUpdate = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

```
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=PRange)
```

To

```
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PRange, _
    xlPivotTableVersion12)
```

The `PivotCaches.Add` method is deprecated and it might be creating a pivot cache in the Excel 2003 version by default. Using `PivotCaches.Create` and specifying `xlPivotTableVersion12` explicitly creates the cache in Excel 2007 format and might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tmdean but I get the same error again. Run-time error '13': Type mismatch